# how to fix mixed(insecure) error in magento v1.9

Tags: ssl, magento, png, magento-1.9, mixed-content

I have this site Https://www.arias.ir .my cms is magento v1.9 .
I have warning in my SSL logo, i found this error
`Loading mixed (insecure) display content “https://arias.ir/media/wysiwyg/logo-nt.png on a secure page`
i also delete this file from my host, but don't slove'd this error.
please help me for slove that.
and also i don't found this HTML code in my site to change it.

`<h2 class="small-logo"><strong></strong><a href="https://arias.ir/" title="" class="logo"><img src="http://arias.ir/media/wysiwyg/logo-nt.png"  alt="" /></a></h2>`

how i can find this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="http://arias.ir/media/wysiwyg/logo-nt.png"  alt="" /></a></h2>
```

As you may have noticed, the problem is that this tag img is trying to load an image from direct URL over http, which is not secure URL.

Since this a logo, as it seems, you may be able to edit it on system configuration. If not, just by editing your theme phtml.

Try accesing your `system -> configuration -> general -> design -> header -> logo src`